# Pass values using function

Tags: arrays, function, 2d

```
 this code is supposed to be a person walking to right in a 4x4 array filled with '*'. for example: if the person walks to the right R ,row zero and walks one step it would look like this: 
   O * * *
   * * * *
   * * * *
   * * * *
 or row one, walks two steps
  * * * * 
  * O * *
  * * * *
  * * * *
 row three, walks four steps
 * * * * 
 * * * *
 * * * * 
 * * * O
```

this is the original code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

  int main ()
  {
  int i,k, c, f;
 char z;

 char a[4][4] = { {'*','*','*','*'}, {'*','*','*','*'}, {'*','*','*','*'}, {'*','*','*','*'}};

    printf("Walking to the right\n");
    z=getchar();

      //  modified array goes here []

    if(z=='R')
    {
        printf("Row\n");
            scanf("%d",&c);

        printf("Steps");
            scanf("%d",&f);
                a[c][f]='O';

        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {

    for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++ ) {
     printf("%c ", a[i][k] );
  }
  printf("\n");
  }
     }
    return ;
 }
```

I would like to have the values for R, row and steps be passed using a function to int main where only the array above is printed.

I tried doing something but I don't really know where to go from here. :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(char);

int main ()
{




 char a[4][4] = { {'*','*','*','*'}, {'*','*','*','*'},      {'*','*','*','*'}, {'*','*','*','*'}};


    printf("From the right\n");
    z=getchar();


      //  modified array goes here []


    void print(char z){
 int i,k;
 int c, f;


    if(z=='R')
    {
        printf("Row\n");
            scanf("%d",&c);


        printf("Steps");
            scanf("%d",&f);
                a[c][f]='O';


        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {


  for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++ ) {
     printf("%c ", a[i][k] );
  }
    printf("\n");
 }
    }
    return ;
 }

 #include <stdio.h>

int main ()
 {


int i,k,x,c,f;

 char z;
 char a[4][4] = { {'*','*','*','*'}, {'*','*','*','*'},{'*','*','*','*'}, {'*','*','*','*'}};


    printf("From the right\n");
    z=getchar();




    printf("Row\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);


    if(z=='R')
    {
        printf("Steps");
        scanf("%d",&f);
        a[c][f]='G';


        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {


  for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++ ) {
     printf("%c ", a[i][k] );
  }
  printf("\n");
  }
    }
    return 0;
   }
```

I'll appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear however look at this:

```
void getCommand(char &z) {
    printf("Walking to the right\n");
    z = getchar();
}

void getRowAndSteps(char z, int &c, int &f) {
    if (z == 'R')
    {
        printf("Row\n");
        scanf("%d", &c);

        printf("Steps");
        scanf("%d", &f);
    }//else...
}

void print(char a[][4]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            printf("%c ", a[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c, f;
    char z;

    char a[4][4] = { { '*','*','*','*' },{ '*','*','*','*' },{ '*','*','*','*' },{ '*','*','*','*' } };



    getCommand(z);
    getRowAndSteps(z, c, f);
    a[c][f] = 'O';

    //maybe some cycle here for each step ??
    print(a);

    return 0;
}
```

or:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Usage: .exe side row steps");
        return 0;
    }

    int c = atoi(argv[2]), f = atoi(argv[3]);
    char z = argv[1][0];

    char a[4][4] = { { '*','*','*','*' },{ '*','*','*','*' },{ '*','*','*','*' },{ '*','*','*','*' } };

    a[c][f] = 'O';

    //maybe some cycle here for each step ??
    print(a);

    return 0;
}
```

untested, hope it will help you